# "no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'" error from GraphQL via re-graph

Tags: clojure, graphql, re-frame

I want to use re-graph to query my graphql api like this:

```clj
; somewhere inside a reg-event-db:
           (rf/dispatch [::rg/query
                         "{ getActiveTrigger { id name eventID  triggerType }}"
                         {}
                         [:graph-trigger-data]])

; event that gets the data:
(rf/reg-event-db :graph-trigger-data
                 (fn [db [_ {:keys [data errors] :as payload}]]
                   (prn payload)
                   db))
```

The print gives this result:

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Failed to parse GraphQL query.\",\"extensions\":{\"errors\":[{\"locations\":[{\"line\":1,\"column\":null}],\"message\":\"no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'\"}]}}]}"
```

The Query itself is valid as I tested it in graphiql.
Google did not provide me with any information what "no viable alternative at input ''" could hint at.
What did I do wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: Can you inspect your network tab and ensure the request looks like what you expect